# 2から始まる偶数を小さい方から順に5個出力するプログラムを作成したい

Tags: python

2から始まる偶数を小さい方から順に5個出力するプログラムを作成したいのですがどうしたらよいでしょうか？偶数にするためのコードはわかるのですがその先が分かりません。

```
n = 0
while n % 2 == 0:
    print(n)
    n += 1
```

実行結果

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

Answer (score 2):

while ループを使っても良いですが、我々は「偶数は整数 2 つごとに存在する」ことや「5 つ目の偶数は 10 である」ことを知っているので、for ループを使う方が見通しが良くなります。

更に、Python の `range` は 3 つ目の引数を渡すことで飛ばし飛ばしの数列を作ることができます。

これらを使うと、以下で書けます。

```
for n in range(2, 10 + 1, 2):
    print(n)
```

今回の問題とは違い条件がもう少し難しくなってどういうときにその条件が満たされるか分からないときは、[Чайка さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/86098/19110)にあるように while ループを使った方が書きやすいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

数を数える変数`n`に加えて、何個出力するか？の変数`limit`を定義します。
あとは、偶数の時、何個出力するか？の変数`limit`を`1`増やし、`while`ループで回します。
つまり、`while`でループを回し、その中で`if`を使い、偶数、奇数を判断します。

```py
n = 1
limit = 0
while limit < 5 :
  if n % 2 == 0 :
    print(n)
    limit = limit + 1
  n = n + 1
```

実行結果

```
2
4
6
8
10
```